# MySQL のコンテナが起動できない

Tags: mysql, docker

**環境**
WSL2(Ubuntu22.04)
Docker
Nginx
Mysql
Phpmyadmin

#### やりたいこと

Mysqlの起動ができないため、原因をつきとめて起動をしたい。

#### 状況

マイグレーションが失敗した→Mysqlが起動していない→Mysqlを起動したい(ここでできない。)

#### 試したこと

.envを修正→Mysqlの再起動(起動ができず、ログを確認したら以下ログ)

#### エラー内容

Mysqlのコンテナログにこのように書いています。

解決策を思い当たる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

※質問が初めてであり分かりづらく大変申し訳ございません。
追加の情報が必要であれば教えてください。

```
2023-03-08 16:12:10+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-03-08 16:12:10+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-03-08 16:12:10+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-03-08T16:12:11.083554+09:00 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-03-08T16:12:11.104796+09:00 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2023-03-08T16:12:11.104836+09:00 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
2023-03-08T16:12:11.119709+09:00 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-03-08T16:12:11.428747+09:00 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-03-08T16:12:11.440037+09:00 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').
2023-03-08T16:12:11.440341+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-03-08T16:12:11.440367+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-08T16:12:11.968129+09:00 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-03-08 16:12:25+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-03-08 16:12:25+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-03-08 16:12:25+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-03-08T16:12:25.761092+09:00 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-03-08T16:12:25.765075+09:00 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2023-03-08T16:12:25.765118+09:00 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
2023-03-08T16:12:25.772182+09:00 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-03-08T16:12:25.887047+09:00 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-03-08T16:12:25.895347+09:00 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').
2023-03-08T16:12:25.896610+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-03-08T16:12:25.896663+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-08T16:12:26.429459+09:00 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Answer (score 2):

> `[ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').`

エラーメッセージから推測するに、DBMS(ファイルシステム)がサポートする大文字/小文字の区別と、`mysqld.cnf`で指定しているそれが食い違っているように見受けます。

DBMSを初期化する際に`lower_case_table_names`を指定する必要があるらしい(初期化後、パラメータを設定し直してもダメ)ので、指定して初期化すると解消すると思います。

＃本家stackoverflowに参考になる投稿があります。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803216/lower-case-table-names-settings-in-mysql-8-0-12